# Get selected value of fabric dropdown

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts, office-ui-fabric-react, reactjs

I want to get value of selected dropdown in my `Visacontact()` function, below is my code:

```
  <Fabric className={styles.matrix2}>
    <VirtualizedComboBox
      styles={comboBoxStyles}
      allowFreeform
      autoComplete="on"
      options={this.state.ddlbookcountry}
      dropdownMaxWidth={200}
      useComboBoxAsMenuWidth
      defaultValue="Please select Key"
    />
  </Fabric>
<input className={styles.button} type='Button' value="Visa Contact" onClick={()=>{this.VisaContact()}}></input>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot directly access the selected value from combo box control in other function. First, you need to store the selected value in `state` variable using `onChange` of combo box selection.

Example:

```
<VirtualizedComboBox
    styles={comboBoxStyles}
    allowFreeform
    autoComplete="on"
    options={this.state.ddlbookcountry}
    onChange={(e, selectedItem, value) => handleChange(e, selectedItem, value)}
    dropdownMaxWidth={200}
    useComboBoxAsMenuWidth
    defaultValue="Please select Key"
/>

handleChange(e, selectedItem, value) {
    let selectedValue = value ? value : selectedItem.text // Set free form entry or selected option text
    this.setState({bookCountryValue: selectedValue});

}
```

This is just an example to show you, how you can save selected option in state.

Then in your `VisaContact()` function, you can access the selected value using `this.state.bookCountryValue`.

**Documentation**:

1. [IComboBoxProps interface - onChange](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/react/icomboboxprops?view=office-ui-fabric-react-latest#onChange)
2. [ComboBox](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fluentui#/controls/web/combobox)

---

**Example code from documentation**:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { ComboBox, IComboBoxOption, IComboBox, SelectableOptionMenuItemType } from 'office-ui-fabric-react/lib/index';

const items: IComboBoxOption[] = [
  { key: 'Header1', text: 'First heading', itemType: SelectableOptionMenuItemType.Header },
  { key: 'A', text: 'Option A' },
  { key: 'B', text: 'Option B' },
  { key: 'C', text: 'Option C' },
  { key: 'D', text: 'Option D' },
  { key: 'divider', text: '-', itemType: SelectableOptionMenuItemType.Divider },
  { key: 'Header2', text: 'Second heading', itemType: SelectableOptionMenuItemType.Header },
  { key: 'E', text: 'Option E' },
  { key: 'F', text: 'Option F', disabled: true },
  { key: 'G', text: 'Option G' },
  { key: 'H', text: 'Option H' },
  { key: 'I', text: 'Option I' },
  { key: 'J', text: 'Option J' },
];

const comboBoxStyle = { maxWidth: 300 };

export const ComboBoxControlledExample: React.FC = () => {
  const [selectedKey, setSelectedKey] = React.useState<string | number | undefined>('C');

  const onChange = React.useCallback(
    (ev: React.FormEvent<IComboBox>, option?: IComboBoxOption): void => {
      setSelectedKey(option?.key);
    },
    [setSelectedKey],
  );

  return (
    <ComboBox
      style={comboBoxStyle}
      selectedKey={selectedKey}
      label="Controlled single-select ComboBox (allowFreeform: T)"
      allowFreeform
      autoComplete="on"
      options={items}
      onChange={onChange}
    />
  );
};
```

Comment: It's work but getting Id and even my combox show empty when I change value

Comment: Can you show us what you have passed in the `options` (this.state.ddlbookcountry)? Also, you can use `.text` instead of `.key` in above code (see updated answer).

Comment: Also, in order to save the selection back to combo box, you need to set the `selectedKey` property of combo box.